# How do I search GitHub API repositories with unauthorized access?

Tags: c#, github-api

I'm trying to create a simple C# application to consume the GitHub API, but when I try to execute the following code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.github.com/users/AndreStoicov/repos") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "GET";
request.Proxy = null;            

using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
         return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

It returns `Protocol Violation Section=ResponseStatusLine` due to me not being an authorized user.

In other words, I want to use the GitHub API without any user authorization; is there any way to perform that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub rules [state](https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required) you must specify `User-Agent` header in request:

```
request.UserAgent = "appname";
```

It does not require registered credentials, just application name would be enough.